# What's wrong with this ruby code? syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

This code comes from the book named Ruby Best Practice:

```
def respond_to?(message)
  message = message.to_sym
  [:__result__, :inspect].include?(message) ||
    __result__.respond_to? message
end
```

But I get an error: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end. What's the matter?

Answer (score 4):

You need some more parenthesis, like so

```
def respond_to?(message)
  message = message.to_sym
  [:__result__, :inspect].include?(message) ||
    __result__.respond_to?(message)
end
```

or (but looks uglier)

```
def respond_to?(message)
  message = message.to_sym
  [:__result__, :inspect].include?(message) ||
    (__result__.respond_to? message)
end
```

anyway what ruby understands is:

```
def respond_to?(message)
  message = message.to_sym
  ([:__result__, :inspect].include?(message) ||
    __result__.respond_to?) message
end
```

because of the operator priority.

I love to call functions without parenthesis, but this is a good thing only when the code is not ambiguous, ruby does not assign any priority to a new line as it does for the `||` function.

Comment: My rule of thumb is: Never call a method without parantheses if you use the return value. That avoids confusion of the parser and the next reader of the code :)

Comment: well... that's very strict, and it wouldn't work for this statement, as it's not the assignment that breaks the code, but the `||` operator, it still makes some sense though

Comment: It would force you to do `respond_to?(message)`, so it wouldn't have that problem. Oh, it doesn't apply for methods with `0` parameters, if that's what you meant :)